# Read text file in project folder in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want read one file .txt in root folder of my project into my database at first time application launch, but I don't know how to do that. Anyone know how can I do that, please help me... Thanks

I'm working in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by old version (WP8.1 Runtime is quite new)? Do you get any exceptions? Have you added file assotiations?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to read a file from your project you can for example do it like this:

```
string fileContent;
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///example.txt"));
using (StreamReader sRead = new StreamReader(await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
fileContent = await sRead.ReadToEndAsync();
```

Also please ensure that you have set the *Build Action* of your file as *Content* (it should be as default).

More about [URI schemes you will find here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx).

Comment: @Jacek There are couple of ways to do it, you should easily find help in internet: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19596135/2681948), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13297563/2681948), [three](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm).

Comment: @Romasz +1 for "Build Action"

Answer (score 9):

A slightly different way to access the file:

```
var folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
var contents = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can only run in `Windows Phone 8.1`. No previous version of windows phone (`Windows Phone 8`, `Windows Phone 7`) would be able to run your app.

Comment: Sorry you, I think my question so confusing, and I fixed it already, thank you for help!