# Read xml data file into Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How can we read a xml data file into `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XMlDocument`? 
The following code is possible only for `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

```
XmlDocument myxml = XmlDocument.Load("abc.xml");
```

Comment: Make sure you call the constructor 1st.  I did it in excel VBA recently using this :     Dim fedbook As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    fedbook.LoadXML strData.  You can read the file as a string and then use LoadXml()

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I read the xml file content to a string, and then use `LoadXml()`:

```
  string fileContent;
  StorageFile tileTemplateFile = 
        await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(@"<path to file>"));
  using (StreamReader reader = 
        new StreamReader(await tileTemplateFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
  {
      fileContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
  }

  XmlDocument tileXml = new XmlDocument();
  tileXml.LoadXml(fileContent);
```

I got most of the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23951961/1438809).

Answer (score -2):

You need to do the following.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();  
xmlDoc.LoadXml(<string representation of your xml>);
```