# How to deploy a file in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

My UWP needs to load a file and I want to know:

1. Where to put this file, in the package installation folder or the application data folder?
2. How to deploy this file to the folder I want when I deploy my app using VS 2015?

Comment: If you want to add a file that will be shipped with the application, add it to your solution, set its build action as content, then you can find it in the [*InstalledLocation* or by URI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23924424/2681948). *AplicationData* folder is used for the data that you add after your app has been installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add files either as resources or content files to your project. If the file is something like a Image, SQLite Database or text file, the best approach will be the `Content` build action.

You can then access the file using `StorageFile.GetFromApplicationUriAsync`:

```
var storeLogoFile = StorageFile.GetFromApplicationUriAsync( 
        new Uri( "ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png" ) );
```

You can also get the `Path` itself if your prefer to use `System.IO`:

```
var packagePath = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var filePath = Path.Combine( packagePath, "Assets/StoreLogo.png" );
//do something with the file
```

This approach however works only if you only need to read the file. If you also need to modify it, you will have to copy it to `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` first:

```
var applicationDataFileCopy = 
     storeLogoFile.CopyAsync( ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder );
```

You might want to do this only once, so you can first check if the file already exists in `ApplicationData` before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. It is a binary file. I do not need to write it, just read it. Is it OK to put it at package installation folder?

Comment: If it solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer as the solution so that the question is resolved :-)

Comment: If you just want to read it, it is ok to put it in the project as a `Content` file and read it from the package installation folder.